# Join apache spark dataframes properly with scala avoiding null values

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, join, apache-spark-sql

Hellow everyone!

I have two DataFrames in apache spark (2.3) and I want to join them properly. I will explain below what I mean with 'properly'. First of all the two dataframes holds the following information:

nodeDf: ( id, year, title, authors, journal, abstract )
edgeDf: ( srcId, dstId, label )

The label could be 0 or 1 in case node1 is connected with node2 or not.

I want to combine this two dataframes to get one dataframe withe the following information:

JoinedDF: ( id_from, year_from, title_from, journal_from, abstract_from, id_to, year_to, title_to, journal_to, abstract_to, time_dist )

time_dist = abs(year_from - year_to)

When I said 'properly' I meant that the query must be as fast as it could be and I don't want to contain null rows or cels ( value on a row ).

I have tried the following but I took me 500 -540 sec to execute the query and the final dataframe contains null values. I don't even know if the dataframes ware joined correctly.

I want to mention that the node file from which I create the nodeDF has 27770 rows and the edge file (edgeDf) has 615512 rows.

Code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Logistic Regression").getOrCreate()
val sc = spark.sparkContext

val data = sc.textFile("resources/data/training_set.txt").map(line =>{
  val fields = line.split(" ")
  (fields(0),fields(1), fields(2).toInt)
})

val data2 = sc.textFile("resources/data/test_set.txt").map(line =>{
  val fields = line.split(" ")
  (fields(0),fields(1))
})

import spark.implicits._
val trainingDF = data.toDF("srcId","dstId", "label")
val testDF = data2.toDF("srcId","dstId")

val infoRDD = spark.read.option("header","false").option("inferSchema","true").format("csv").load("resources/data/node_information.csv")

val infoDF = infoRDD.toDF("srcId","year","title","authors","jurnal","abstract")

println("Showing linksDF sample...")
trainingDF.show(5)
println("Rows of linksDF: ",trainingDF.count())

println("Showing infoDF sample...")
infoDF.show(2)
println("Rows of infoDF: ",infoDF.count())

println("Joining linksDF and infoDF...")
var joinedDF = trainingDF.as("a").join(infoDF.as("b"),$"a.srcId" === $"b.srcId")

println(joinedDF.count())

joinedDF = joinedDF.select($"a.srcId",$"a.dstId",$"a.label",$"b.year",$"b.title",$"b.authors",$"b.jurnal",$"b.abstract")

joinedDF.show(5)


val graphX = new GraphX()
val pageRankDf =graphX.computePageRank(spark,"resources/data/training_set.txt",0.0001)

println("Joining joinedDF and pageRankDf...")
joinedDF = joinedDF.as("a").join(pageRankDf.as("b"),$"a.srcId" === $"b.nodeId")

var dfWithRanks = joinedDF.select("srcId","dstId","label","year","title","authors","jurnal","abstract","rank").withColumnRenamed("rank","pgRank")
dfWithRanks.show(5)

println("Renameming joinedDF...")
dfWithRanks = dfWithRanks
  .withColumnRenamed("srcId","id_from")
  .withColumnRenamed("dstId","id_to")
  .withColumnRenamed("year","year_from")
  .withColumnRenamed("title","title_from")
  .withColumnRenamed("authors","authors_from")
  .withColumnRenamed("jurnal","jurnal_from")
  .withColumnRenamed("abstract","abstract_from")

var infoDfRenamed = dfWithRanks
  .withColumnRenamed("id_from","id_from")
  .withColumnRenamed("id_to","id_to")
  .withColumnRenamed("year_from","year_to")
  .withColumnRenamed("title_from","title_to")
  .withColumnRenamed("authors_from","authors_to")
  .withColumnRenamed("jurnal_from","jurnal_to")
  .withColumnRenamed("abstract_from","abstract_to").select("id_to","year_to","title_to","authors_to","jurnal_to","jurnal_to")

var finalDF = dfWithRanks.as("a").join(infoDF.as("b"),$"a.id_to" === $"b.srcId")

finalDF = finalDF
  .withColumnRenamed("year","year_to")
  .withColumnRenamed("title","title_to")
  .withColumnRenamed("authors","authors_to")
  .withColumnRenamed("jurnal","jurnal_to")
  .withColumnRenamed("abstract","abstract_to")

println("Dropping unused columns from joinedDF...")
finalDF = finalDF.drop("srcId")

finalDF.show(5)
```

Here are my results!

[image]

Avoid all calculations and code related to pgRank! Is there any proper way to do this join works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use <=> operator in your joining column condition

```
var joinedDF = trainingDF.as("a").join(infoDF.as("b"),$"a.srcId" <=> $"b.srcId")
```

There is a function in spark 2.1 or greater is **eqNullSafe**

```
var joinedDF = trainingDF.join(infoDF,trainingDF("srcId").eqNullSafe(infoDF("srcId")))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your data first and then join, in that case you will avoid nulls

df.filter($"ColumnName".isNotNull)